# Injecting an annotated Service in a Provider in Angular

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service

I would like to use a Service in a Provider. I'm not sure it's the right way to go.

I've managed to instantiate a service in a provider, by injecting the service provider instead, and calling its .$get() method.

If the service itself requires some dependencies, it gets harder. It keeps working if the dependencies are inferred: I get to call .$get(), which returns the correct function and get the dependencies right.

But If I try dependency annotation, as it's the only way to work through minification, $get() returns the annotation array as I defined it. I thought I could then use injector.$invoke(),but it seems it cannot resolve dependencies anymore.

I created a Plunker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tPlF3vQUmWGHt46q3Aaa?p=preview

Things get tricky at line 90, and line 112 is where my problem lies.